# formatting csv file genereted by php horizontally

Tags: php, csv

I've written a code that converts a mysql data into csv file. The problem is that it shows result horizontally as

```
DATE        AUTHOR  LIKES   COMMENTS`
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 3
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23

DATE        AUTHOR  LIKES   COMMENTS`
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 3
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23
```

however i want it vertically as

```
DATE        AUTHOR  LIKES   COMMENTS`   DATE    AUTHOR     LIKES    COMMENTS`
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 3           1/31/2013   WTF Facts  211      23
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23          1/31/2013   WTF Facts  211      23
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23          1/31/2013   WTF Facts  211      3
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23          1/31/2013   WTF Facts  211      23
1/31/2013   WTF Facts   211 23          1/31/2013   WTF Facts  211      23
```

Here is my code:

```
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
        set_time_limit(99999999);
        ini_set('memory_limit', "9999M");
        $filename_csv = "export_".rand(1000000,9999999)."_".rand(1000000,9999999).".csv";
        $path = "serp_csvs_page/".$filename_csv;
        $fp = fopen($path, 'w');
        $page_ids = $_POST['page_id'];
        $date_from =  $_POST['date_from'];
        $date_to = $_POST['date_to'];

        foreach($page_ids as $page_id):
            $brline = array("\n");
            $page_name = get_page_name_by_id($page_id);
            $dates = checkCsvQuotes("DATE: FROM {$date_from} TO {$date_to}") ;
            $page_name = checkCsvQuotes("PAGE ID: {$page_name['page_id']}");
            $header = array($dates, "\n", $page_name);
            fputcsv($fp, $header);
            fputcsv($fp, $brline);
            $query = sprintf("SELECT post_date AS `DATE`, post_from AS `AUTHOR`, message AS `MESSAGE`, total_likes AS `TOTAL LIKES`, total_comments AS `TOTAL COMMENTS` FROM tbl_contents_pages WHERE `pid_id` = '$page_id' AND `post_date` >= '$date_from' AND `post_date` <= '$date_to'");
            $result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error($con));
            $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            if ($rows) {
                $arr_key = array_keys($rows); 
                fputcsv($fp, $arr_key);
                while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $date_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['DATE']);
                    $author_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['AUTHOR']);
                    $message_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['MESSAGE']);
                    $likes_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['TOTAL LIKES']);
                    $comments_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['TOTAL COMMENTS']);
                    $arr_value = array();
                    $arr_value[] = $date_row;
                    $arr_value[] = $author_row;
                    $arr_value[] = $message_row;
                    $arr_value[] = $likes_row;
                    $arr_value[] = $comments_row;
                    //print_r($arr_value);
                    fputcsv($fp, $arr_value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $noData = array("DO RECORDS FOUND.");
                fputcsv($fp, $noData);
            }
            fputcsv($fp, $brline);
        endforeach;
        fclose($fp);
        echo "<a href=serp_csvs_page/".$filename_csv." class='btn btn-primary'> View File </a>";  
        endif;
      function get_page_name_by_id($id)
        {
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT page_id FROM tbl_pages WHERE `id` = '$id'");
            $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            return $result;
        }
    function checkCsvQuotes($string) 
    {
        if (strpos($string,'"') !== false) {
            return '"'.str_replace('"','""',$string).'"';
        } elseif (strpos($string,',') !== false) {
            return '"'.$string.'"';
        } else {
            return $string;
        }
    }
      ?>
```

Im not sure even if its possible, since im new with csv. I would greatly appreciate if you guys have any idea bout it and sharae with me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep extending the array, not instantly spit the elements out. I've changed your code to do so, but as I'm unable to test it, it may very likely not work. Either way, compare the code to get the idea of what needs to be done.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
    set_time_limit(99999999);
    ini_set('memory_limit', "9999M");
    $filename_csv = "export_".rand(1000000,9999999)."_".rand(1000000,9999999).".csv";
    $path = "serp_csvs_page/".$filename_csv;
    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');
    $page_ids = $_POST['page_id'];
    $date_from =  $_POST['date_from'];
    $date_to = $_POST['date_to'];

    $data_ar = array(); //create a "master" array
    $i = $j = 0;

    foreach($page_ids as $page_id):
        $brline = array("\n");
        $page_name = get_page_name_by_id($page_id);
        $dates = checkCsvQuotes("DATE: FROM {$date_from} TO {$date_to}") ;
        $page_name = checkCsvQuotes("PAGE ID: {$page_name['page_id']}");
        $header = array($dates, "\n", $page_name);
        fputcsv($fp, $header);
        fputcsv($fp, $brline);
        $query = sprintf("SELECT post_date AS `DATE`, post_from AS `AUTHOR`, message AS `MESSAGE`, total_likes AS `TOTAL LIKES`, total_comments AS `TOTAL COMMENTS` FROM tbl_contents_pages WHERE `pid_id` = '$page_id' AND `post_date` >= '$date_from' AND `post_date` <= '$date_to'");
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error($con));
        $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($rows) {
            $arr_key = array_keys($rows); 
            fputcsv($fp, $arr_key);
            $i = 0; //set to 0 on each iteration over $page_ids
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $date_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['DATE']);
                $author_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['AUTHOR']);
                $message_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['MESSAGE']);
                $likes_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['TOTAL LIKES']);
                $comments_row = checkCsvQuotes($rows['TOTAL COMMENTS']);
                if ($j === 0) //note: this assumes all files have the same amount of data
                    $data_ar[$i] = array();
                $data_ar[$i][] = $date_row; //these will add to array data instead of creating new array rows
                $data_ar[$i][] = $author_row;
                $data_ar[$i][] = $message_row;
                $data_ar[$i][] = $likes_row;
                $data_ar[$i][] = $comments_row;
                //print_r($arr_value);
                $i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $noData = array("DO RECORDS FOUND.");
            fputcsv($fp, $noData);
        }
        $j++;
    endforeach;
    for ($q = 0; $q < count($data_ar); $q++) { //insert data to file once the data has been gathered
        fputcsv($fp, $data_ar[$q]);
        fputcsv($fp, $brline);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    echo "<a href=serp_csvs_page/".$filename_csv." class='btn btn-primary'> View File </a>";  
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: thnk you mustafa... will let you know if its okay.. :)